# Do you lose your nomad tile if you move all your settlements away?

Tags: kingdom-builder

*Kingdom Builder* with *Nomads* expansion

If you are the first who builds adjacent to a nomads space, you get the (only) nomads tile.

Do you lose it when you move all your settlements away from the nomad space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, [according to](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9524984#9524984) the game designer *Donald X. Vaccarino*:

> I do not see this in the rulebook, but the intention was that you do not lose the tile, even if you immediately move away.